# insert_id() returns blank array with sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I’m using Codeigniter 2.1.4 and Ion Auth 2 and when a new user is created the ID doesn’t get returned, instead a blank array is returned. I’m having to use MSSQL so am using the sqlsrv driver. In sqlsrv_driver.php the code looks like:

```
function insert_id()
 {
  return $this->query('select @@IDENTITY as insert_id')->row('insert_id');
 }
```

If I echo what this function returns it returns a blank array. Does anyone have a fix for this as nothing I have tried so far has worked and I haven’t found a solution yet on Google!

Unfortunately the client is insisting on using MSSQL so I am stuck with this. Using MSSQL driver didn’t work hence why I’m using sqlsrv. The code all worked perfectly when it was developed on MySQL, it’s only since the switch to using MSSQL that I’ve encountered this problem (amongst others!).

Comment: I have since tried using @@identity outside of CodeIgniter, i.e., with straight PHP and it also returns a blank so I believe it must be the SQLSRV drivers at fault. The same SQL statement works fine in SQL Studio Manager so there's nothing wrong with my table schema. Has anyone come across this and know how to fix it?